# How to match strings in a DB2 (z/OS) query?

Tags: db2, mainframe, zos

This is blowing my mind.

All I want to do is basic string comparison on a long `varchar` field.

I have a table of approx. 12M records.

If I query for `MY_FIELD='a string'`, I get a count of 25947, which seems about right.

If I query for `MY_FIELD!='a string'`, I get a count of 989.

Shouldn't these 2 counts add up to the full table size of 12M?

Answer (score 6):

And in how many of those rows is `MY_FIELD` set to `NULL`?

```
a. select count(*) from mytable;
b. select count(*) from mytable where my_field is null;
c. select count(*) from mytable where my_field is not null;
d. select count(*) from mytable where my_field = 'some value';
e. select count(*) from mytable where my_field != 'some value';
```

`NULL` is not equal or unequal to *any* value, including `NULL` so I would expect `d+e` to equate to `c` and `b+c` to equate to `a`.

Comment: Thanks Pax. That was the issue! Duh.